# output generated macro content with newline

Tags: macros, line-breaking

I would like to debug a latex macro, but I do not really know how. I got the following MWE which replaces the `\\` in a string. I would like to print the value of generated string to check the result. The first output of `\show` is as expected `\textbf {Test123\\Test234}`. Now I would like to output the macro `\addrGlobal`, so that it shows `\textbf {Test123\newline Test234}`, but it does not work as expected. How can this output be archieved?

Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.27cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xstring}


\def\address{\textbf{Test123\\Test234}}

\newcommand{\addrGlobal}{%
\ifx\@empty\address\else
\saveexpandmode\expandarg
\StrSubstitute{\address}{\empty\\}{\empty\newline}[\addr]%
\restoreexpandmode\addr%
}%

\relax
\show\address
\show\addrGlobal


\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should add `\usepackage{xstring}`, and then I think you want to look at `\addr` (after invoking `\addrGlobal`), _not_ `\addrGlobal`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various issues in your code.

1. Why checking whether `\address` is empty? You have just defined it not to be
2. `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are missing around the code that uses `\@empty`
3. The string `\empty\\` doesn't appear in `\address`, so nothing is changed.
4. `\addrGlobal` will not contain a string, but rather `\addr`, when `\addrGlobal` is executed, which isn't in your code. Until you don't issue `\addrGlobal`, no value will be given to `\addr`.

Here's a possible fix.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\def\address{\textbf{Test123\\Test234}}

\newcommand{\fixaddress}{%
  \saveexpandmode\expandarg\exploregroups
  \StrSubstitute{\address}{\noexpand\\}{\newline}[\addrGlobal]%
  \restoreexpandmode
}    

\show\address
\fixaddress
\show\addrGlobal
```

Note `\noexpand\\` in order not to expand the string to be searched and `\exploregroups`. The `\ifx\@empty\address` test is useless, because if the string is empty, no substitution will be performed.

Here is the output on the terminal:

```
> \address=macro:
->\textbf {Test123\\Test234}.
l.13 \show\address

?
> \addrGlobal=macro:
->\textbf {Test123\protect \newline  Test234}.
l.15 \show\addrGlobal
```