# cellspacebreak macro

Tags: tables, macros, line-breaking

(I am rolling my own little system to take my LaTeX file and convert it to reasonable HTML and Epub. I have run into the following problem.)

I would like to keep my `tabular`s very simple.  There are some (header) cells that I would like to have broken at spaces.

```
\begin{tabular}{lr}
                & long column name \\
    interesting & 2
\end{tabular}
```

inside a tabular, using a `\\` is hazardous.  I also do not want to make my `tabular` programming very complex.  Ideally, I want a macro

```
\begin{tabular}{lr}
                & \cellspacebreak{long column name} \\
    interesting & 2
\end{tabular}
```

that breaks spaces to lines, as if I had had `\begin{minipage}{\widestwidth} long\\column\\name \end{minipage}`.  this is probably easier in LuaTeX, but I need a solution for pdfTeX.  I also have a preference, not absolute, to stick to the standard tabular environment.  both of these are necessitated by the fact that a number of users will use this, and they may not have very recent TeX installations or sophistication.

Does this exist?

Comment: In order to generate the HTML or Epub, are you at all looking at the LaTeX code, or just processing the PDF output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two options:

1. Replace the space character   with `\\` using [`xstring`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring):

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage{xstring}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring

   % Ideas from Output generated macro content with newline (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124810/5764)
   \newcommand{\cellspacebreak}[1]{%
     \saveexpandmode\expandarg\exploregroups
     \StrSubstitute{#1}{ }{\noexpand\\}[\cellwithlinebreaks]%
     \restoreexpandmode%
     \show\cellwithlinebreaks
     \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
       \cellwithlinebreaks
     \end{tabular}
   }    

   \begin{document}

   \begin{tabular}{lr}
                   & \cellspacebreak{long column name} \\
       interesting & 2
   \end{tabular}

   \end{document}
   ```
2. Use LaTeX3 to iterate over your "space-separated list" if items:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
   \ExplSyntaxOn

   % Taken from How to iterate over a comma separated list? (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159118/5764)
   \NewDocumentCommand{\cellspacebreak}{ m }
    {
     \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
     \xyz_break_items:n { #1 }
     \end{tabular}
    }

   \seq_new:N \l_xyz_input_seq
   \cs_new_protected:Npn \xyz_break_items:n #1
    {
     \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_xyz_input_seq { ~ } { #1 }
     \seq_use:Nn \l_xyz_input_seq { \\ }
    }

   \ExplSyntaxOff

   \begin{document}

   \begin{tabular}{lr}
                   & \cellspacebreak{long column name} \\
       interesting & 2
   \end{tabular}

   \end{document}
   ```

In both instances the output resembles:

[image]

Comment: I've taken the liberty of simplifying your LaTeX3 code

Comment: @egreg: Awesome!

Comment: Bruno deserves all credits for `\seq_use:Nn`, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

A `\Longstack` could be the thing.  The `[l]` causes left alignment in the stack (`[c]` and `[r]` are options, too, for center- and right-alignment).  I also need to reset the longstack gapsize in the preamble, because `\baselineskip` is set to 0pt in a `tabular`.  The default `\Longstack` uses spaces as the end-of-line separators, unless reset with `\setstackEOL{\\}` or some such reassignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\edef\tmp{\the\baselineskip}
\setstackgap{L}{\tmp}
\def\cellspacebreak{\Longstack[l]}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
                & \cellspacebreak{long column name} \\
    interesting & 2
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the darn system only allows me to count one answer as being the solution.  this is a good second solution (and in fact the one I am using now).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are really looking for a `p{}` column, but at least for your example table this basic solution is enough:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lp{1.5cm}}
                & long column name \\
    interesting & 2
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Note that inside a wider column (`p{5cm}`, for example) you can force the line breaks with  the `\newline` command:

```
                & long \newline column \newline  name \\
```

Comment: thx.  indeed, this is different.  good for reference for readers who do not know this.  I did.